# I don't have "many/enough" friends for a large party - many or enough?

Tags: word-choice, usage

We can say the following sentences:

> (a) I don't have **enough** friends for a large party.

> (b) I don't have **enough** hair for a haircut.

But when something requires a lot of something else, can I use **many**, **much** or a **number** in a similar sentence?

> (1) I don't have **many** friends for a large party. (because a large party requires many friends.)

> (2) I don't have **much** hair for a haircut. (because I think a haircut requires a lot of hair.)

> (3) I don't have **ten** people for a task force. (because a task force requires ten people.)

Comment: Much goes with uncountable nouns; many with countable nouns.

Comment: So all of (1), (2), and (3) are correct, right?

Comment: I don't find any of them very idiomatic. I would prefer _enough_ for the first two (though surely the need for a haircut depends on length, not thickness?)  and "I don't have the ten people I need for a task force".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Enough* is used when you've met or exceeded some requirement. Saying *I don't have enough* means the emphasis is on **not** meeting that requirement, lacking something that you need, being unable to successfully do something, etc. The point is that you need **more**.

*Don't have many/much* doesn't really mean the same thing, because you're not talking about meeting (or failing to meet) a requirement. Those words are more of a general opinion about whether something seems like a lot, or not much, in a particular scenario:

- *it's not cold enough* (a particular low temperature is required, and we haven't reached it - this implies a specific problem!)
- *it's not very cold* (a general opinion on how low the temperature seems - even if this might cause a specific problem, there's no context suggesting that)

As for your examples:

1. I think this would be fine if it were just *I don't have many friends for a party*, that would sound like "if I had a party, the number of friends I could invite wouldn't seem like very many". It might feel a little empty or quiet. *Large* sounds awkward because that implies a certain number of people to count as "large", and *enough* would work better because of that sense of "I don't have the number of friends I need to throw a *large* party".
2. Again, *enough* works better because it has that sense of "there's no point getting a haircut, because I would need more hair for it to be worthwhile". *Much* sort of implies you would get a haircut anyway, and you just wanted to talk about how little you'd actually be getting cut. I feel like that situation is much more unusual, but I think you *could* say it if it applied? It seems fine, just not something people would usually say!
3. *Ten* is completely fine here, you're being specific about the required number. With *enough* you're generally not being specific about what the requirement *is* exactly, just whether or not you've met it. Actually saying *ten* is the same thing, just more specific!